# After format, unknown filesystem on boot, bootable usb cannot mount /dev/loop0 goes to initramfs

Tags: boot, partitioning, grubrescue, initramfs

So I have really managed to mess things up. I have Ubuntu 19.10 on a 2018 [Lenovo Ideapad 520-15IKB](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-IdeaPad-520-15IKB-81BF00CXHV.309398.0.html). The SSD drive had been encrypted when I installed Ubuntu from scratch.

Yesterday I tried to create a bootable USB stick, and accidentally formatted the dev/sda1/ partition. Not only that, but I also wrote the Ubuntu .iso image with dd on top of it.

It is possible that dd failed.

I later succeeded, also with dd, in creating a proper bootable USB stick (tested it on another laptop and it works).

Now:
when I boot from the hard-drive, I get this message and the grub rescue prompt

```
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

when i try to launch Try Ubuntu without installing from the USB drive, I get the following:

```
[sdb] asking for cache data failed
[sdb] assuming drive cache: write through
blk_update request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 2989312 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0xB0700 phys_seg 1 prio class O
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 2989312 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class O
Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 373664, async page read
I/O error, dev loop0, sector 2989312 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0xB0700 phys_seg 1 prio class O
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 2989312 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class O
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x5b3bbfcb
squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read xattr id index table


BusyBox v 1.30.1 [...]

(initramfs) Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: input/output error
Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

Now, I've tested the USB stick with another computer and I can try Ubuntu without installing just fine.

What can I do? Preferably with the tools on board, since I don't have easy administrator access to a Windows computer to use their boot rescue tools. I could potentially get my hands on Macbook Pro.

I don't need to recover any data, just to be able to fix it and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: What is the most important thing to do? Are the most important files in the internal drive backed up? Or must you try hard to recover what can still be recovered? -- Anyway, please tell us the model name/number of the Lenovo computer. Knowing that will help us help you boot it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction! I only want to fix it, no need to recover anything. The laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad 520 with an SSD drive, which was encrypted. I've added the information in the main question too.

Comment: A common problem with new nvidia graphics is that the built-in linux drivers need some help. You can try the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried, getting the same errors as indicated in the second code box above.

Comment: Are you booting from the USB stick?

Comment: Yes, I'm booting from the USB stick, then changed the option nomodeset in Other Options, then Try Ubuntu without installing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105650/discussion-between-sudodus-and-lavinia-teodorescu).

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion in a linked chat room, the problem was solved.

- There was an error on the live USB stick, and you found it by running 'Check the disk for defects' from the boot menu. It appears that this error was preventing loading the filesystem on the bootable USB stick.
- Downloading a new image (Ubuntu 18.04.4) and flashing the image onto it (this time using Etcher 1.5) resulted in a bootable USB stick that allowed to reinstall Ubuntu.
- Running Ubuntu live booted from the USB stick, it was possible to format the HDD, thereby restoring the faulty partition.